# Same image appearing on render but not in source with gridfs-stream (mongoose & mongo driver)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I'm having a strange issue wherein images are being shown more than once on the index, but shows the correct series of images per post in the permalink view.

I'm using this controller, routed to `/grid/:id`

```
exports.getById = function(req, res){
  id = req.params.id;
  var conn = mongoose.createConnection(res.locals.db);
  conn.once('open', function(){
    var gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.files.find({ _id: ObjectID(id) }).toArray(function(err, files){
      if (err) throw new Error(err);
      // console.log(files);
      res.set('Content-Type', files[0].contentType);
    });
    var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({ _id: id });
    readstream.pipe(res);
  });
};
```

Screenshots are the easiest way for me to explain what's going on.

Here's the index as it's currently being rendered *(notice that there is two different links here, but the same image is being shown)*:
[image: Index page]

Here's an inspection of the first image in the Web Inspector:
[image]

Upon closer inspection…
[image]

However, if I go to that post's permalink page, randomly it will either show me the correct image or the same image again. However if I drag the first image to the address bar and then hit back, it shows the right image again:
[image]

Until I hit refresh…
[image]

My first guess was that it was sending the incorrect `ContentType`, but now the code sends that with `res.set('ContentType', files[0].contentType)`; this works, but even setting it manually to `'image/png'` does not fix it.

I've also made a second controller for using the standard `mongodb` driver, but I get the same exact error.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

exports.mongoGet = function(req, res){
  id = req.params.id;
  var db = new mongo.Db('database', new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017), {safe: true});
  db.open(function (err){
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    var gfs = Grid(db, mongo);
    var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({ _id: ObjectID(id) });
    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    readstream.pipe(res);  
  });
};
```

This is running me through a huge loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `id` variable is global and will be overwritten with every new request, clobbering the previous value.

So:

```
exports.mongoGet = function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  ^^^
  ...
};
```

Added tip: you don't have to create a new Mongoose connection for each request, that's not very efficient. Just do it once somewhere at the start of your app; by default, Mongoose will automatically reconnect to MongoDB in case of disconnects.

Comment: oh geez.. thanks for that. Would you recommend just connecting to the database on app init?